# Maven does not take newly built snapshot, uses global repository

Tags: maven, snapshot

I am trying to build a patch branch, into which I build both a parent(a snapshot) and a child(a snapshot as well) as modules listed in an aggregation pom.

Maven finds out everyone depends on the parent, and builds it first, *BUT* it does not use the newly built parent when I build into clean repository.

When built immediately afterwards, against the same repository, that the built Parent 2.2.5- Snapshot is installed in already, everything works correctly and the patched parent is used in its children.

The problem is that the CI build is always built on a clean repo, and hence, the parent that we use is the one from the global repository, not the local one.

Is this wrong pom.xml, maven settings or possible a bug in maven algorithm?

I tried

```
mvn clean install -nsu
```

but in vain.

Comment: do you call maven in the aggregation pom directory, the parent directory or the child directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the major problem was that we were building the parent pom together with the rest.
Maven **downloads all parents first** and then resolves dependencies.

So, it was not correct that the parent is listed together with the rest, as a module, when this is a clean build and this version of the parent was not yet deployed(children saw an old snapshot of it instead).

**Solution 1:** **use relativePath to point to the branched parent**. This is the better solution in case you do not have very complex hierarchy of modules.

**Solution 2:** **build and deploy the parent of the patch first**, so that it is seen by all children, and hence they use correct versions of each other.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the option `-nsu` which means:

> -nsu,--no-snapshot-updates             Suppress SNAPSHOT updates

It will never use the most up-to-date snapshots. To force maven to do so you should use:

```
mvn -U clean install
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @khmarbaise, but the problem was that Maven did not see *the local* newly built snapshot. -U did not help, you can see my comment below for details.